# How can I find the installation folder after the installation is complete?

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup

I am trying to write an extension installer, but have to locate the prerequisite application's INSTALLDIR.  The prerequisite application is installed with MSI.  The extension installer is using Inno Setup.

Any hints on where I can get this information from?

I have looked into the Windows uninstall registry, but the InstallLocation value is blank.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{MY-PRODUCTID-GUID-HERE}]
"Comments"=""
"Contact"=""
"DisplayVersion"="1.0.0"
"HelpLink"=""
"HelpTelephone"=""
"InstallDate"="20111021"
"InstallLocation"=""
"InstallSource"="D:\\Documents\\Downloads\\"
"URLUpdateInfo"=""
"VersionMajor"=dword:00000001
"VersionMinor"=dword:00000000
"WindowsInstaller"=dword:00000001
"Version"=dword:01000000
"Language"=dword:00000409
"DisplayName"="MyApp (64-bit)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSI doesn't restrict a package to having a single installation directory, so there's no way to query for one. If you want to offer extensibility like that, pick a directory and write it to the registry for others to query.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way out of this problem is to attempt to navigate to the default install directory of the prerequisite. If it can't be found, prompt the user for the path to the install directory.

I use NSIS. so, in those terms it goes something like this:

```
    Function .onInit

  Pop $R1 ; "c:\\Program Files\ etc...."

  # Check if it is installed
  StrCmp $R1
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP $(NotInstalled)
    Abort

  # It is installed so set INSTDIR
  StrCpy $INSTDIR "$R1"

FunctionEnd
```

Comment: That would be my fallback plan - but I am assuming that Windows Installer must have the location of the INSTALLDIR used stored somewhere?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know where it would be cached, if it is indeed cached. I understand that you want a big green button that just says "GO" but that requires really stringent dependency policies. One possible addition is if you could package your dependencies installers with your own and then you decide the install directory.

Comment: I would assume it needs to be cached somewhere - how else can uninstall work? - it might be inaccessible?

Comment: Inaccessible = not cached for your purposes. Either way, it would be delving deep into the bowels of Windows to find out and if it turns out that it's controlled by the program itself then you would need to delve deep down into that documentation.

Comment: Perhaps call MsiGetComponentPath on a known ProductCode and Component ID, assuming there's a way to call C++ functions.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in that location, you could ask the authors of the main package to see if they store the path anywhere. If not, DevinBM's suggestion is the only practical way.

Comment: I can ask him - but people start thinking I'm crazy when I talk to myself.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Install applications are not required to write `InstallLocation` to `Uninstall` registry key, however it's *recommended*. Yet you have to take care of it yourself when developing installation package.

The program could have written this value into its own key in the registry, for example: `HKLM\Software\MyApp`.

If prerequisite is yours, then modify the installer so that it writes the directory where extensions should be installed into the registry, as [suggested by Bob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335060/572834).